# Python RegEx , how to find words that start with uppercase followed by lower case?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

```
Date: 20/8/2020 Duration: 0.33 IP: 110.1.x.x Server:01
```

I'm applying `findall` as a way to split my string when I apply `findall` it split I & P how can I change expression to get this output

```
['Date: 20/8/2020 ', 'Duration: 0.33 ', 'IP: 110.1.x.x ', 'Server:01']
```

```
text = "Date: 20/8/2020 Duration: 0.33 IP: 110.1.x.x Server:01"
my_list = re.findall('[a-zA-Z][^A-Z]*', text)
my_list

['Date: 20/8/2020 ', 'Duration: 0.33 ', 'I', 'P: 110.1.x.x ', 'Server:01']
```

Comment: https://www.autoregex.xyz/ play here.

Comment: Why don't you look for any word followed by semicolon ? For the server part are you sure there's no missing space between "Server: 01" rather than "Server:01" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for any string that begins with either two uppercase letters, or an uppercase followed by a lowercase, and then match until you find either the same pattern or end of line.

```
>>> re.findall(r'([A-Z][a-zA-Z].*?)\s*(?=[A-Z][a-zA-Z]|$)', text)
['Date: 20/8/2020', 'Duration: 0.33', 'IP: 110.1.x.x', 'Server:01']
```

You may also wish to use this to create a dictionary.

```
>>> dict(re.split(r'\s*:\s*', m, 1) for m in re.findall(r'([A-Z][a-zA
-Z].*?)\s*(?=[A-Z][a-zA-Z]|$)', text))
{'Date': '20/8/2020', 'Duration': '0.33', 'IP': '110.1.x.x', 'Server': '01'}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked :) can you please explain what each expression mean ?

Comment: `[A-Z]` is a single character that can be any uppercase letter. `[a-zA-Z]` is a single character that can be either upper or lowercase.  `.` is any character. `.*?` is a non-greedy match of zero or more characters. `\s` is a whitespace character. `\s*` is zero or more whitespace characters. Then the `(?=...)` is a non-matching group. `$` is end-of-line.

Answer (score 0):

With Regex you should always be as precise as possible.
So if you know that your input data always looks like that, I would suggest writing the full words in Regex.

If that's not what you want you have to make a sacrifice of certainty:

1. Change Regex to accept any word containing letters of any size at any position
2. Add capital P as following letter
3. Add IP as special case

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(?<!\S)[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*:\s*\S+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)`
- `[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*:` Match an uppercase char A-Z, optional chars a-zA-Z followed by `:`
- `\s*\S` Match optional whitespace chars and 1+ non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w5gReB/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<!\S)[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*:\s*\S+"
s = "Date: 20/8/2020 Duration: 0.33 IP: 110.1.x.x Server:01"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['Date: 20/8/2020', 'Duration: 0.33', 'IP: 110.1.x.x', 'Server:01']
```

Comment: Thank you both Chris answer & yours worked perfectly

Comment: This doesn't quite hit the spec of two characters as using `s = "Date: 20/8/2020 Duration: 0.33 I: 110.1.x.x Server:01"` will still yield: `['Date: 20/8/2020', 'Duration: 0.33', 'I: 110.1.x.x', 'Server:01']`. Perhaps you want your pattern to be `r"(?<!\S)[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+:\s*\S+"` swapping the `*` for `+`.

Comment: @Chris It gives the expected result.